# Ruby Read CSV and pick out variables

Tags: ruby, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to read CSV in Ruby. FasterCSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369039/best-way-to-read-csv-in-ruby-fastercsv)

Is it possible to have Ruby read through a CSV file, line by line and use the contents of the line to set as different variables?

e.g. one line is `Matt,Masters,18-04-1993` and I want to split the line and use:

- Matt = firstname
- Masters = surname
- 18-04-1993 = dob

so far I have:

```
require 'uri/http'
require 'csv'

File.open("filename.csv").readlines.each do |line|

d = line.split(",")

puts d

end
```

Comment: Why are you requiring `'uri/http'` and not using the CSV module after requiring it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do it

```
File.open("filename.csv").readlines.each do |line|
  CSV.parse do |line|
    firstname, surname, dob = line
    #you can access the above 3 variables now
  end
end
```

Now will be able to use `firstname`, `surname` and `dob` in the block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the help! :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Rely on CSV to split the line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this...

```
File.open("filename.csv").read.split("\n").each do |line|
  first_name, last_name, age = line.split(",")
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! worked first time thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Correct, no splat needed here.

Comment: This will fail badly when splitting a CSV record containing embedded commas inside strings. The CSV file format is much more complicated than it appears so use the CSV module to handle parsing it.